# Trace back original position of argmin/argmax on boolean masked NumPy array - Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations, masked-array

***Context***

Since masking with the `numpy.ma`-module is significantly slower than direct boolean masking, I have to use the latter for my `argmin`/`argmax`-calculations.

A little comparison:

```py
import numpy as np

# Masked Array
arr1 = np.ma.masked_array([12,4124,124,15,15], mask=[0,1,1,0,1])

# Boolean masking
arr2 = np.array([12,4124,124,15,15])
mask = np.array([0,1,1,0,1], dtype=np.bool)

%timeit arr1.argmin()
# 16.1 µs ± 4.88 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit arr2[mask].argmin()
# 946 ns ± 55.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Anyhow, using `argmin`/`argmax` returns the index of the first occurrence within the array. In case of boolean masking this means the index within `arr2[mask]` and not `arr2`. And there is my problem: **I need the index within the unmasked array while calculating it on the masked array**.



***Question***

*How can I get the `argmin`/`argmax`-index of the unmasked `arr2`, even when I apply it to the boolean masked version `arr2[mask]`?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one based mostly on `masking`, specifically - `mask-the-mask` and should be memory-efficient and hopefully good on performance too, especially when dealing with large arrays -

```
def reset_first_n_True(mask, n):
    # Resets (fills with False) first n True places in mask

    # Count of True in original mask array
    c = np.count_nonzero(mask)

    # Setup second mask that is to be assigned into original mask on its
    # own True positions with the idea of setting first argmin_in_masked_ar
    # True values to False
    second_mask = np.ones(c, dtype=bool)
    second_mask[:n] = False
    mask[mask] = second_mask
    return

# Use reduction function on masked data array 
idx = np.argmin(random_array[random_mask])
reset_first_n_True(random_mask, idx)
out = random_mask.argmax()
```

To get argmax on the masked data array and trace it back to original position, only the first step would change to include that :

```
idx = np.argmax(random_array[random_mask])
```

So, any reduction operation could be used and traced back to their original positions that way.

---

If you are looking for a compact solution, use `nonzero()` -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(random_mask)
out = idx[random_array[random_mask].argmin()]
# Or idx[random_array[idx].argmin()]
```

Comment: Nice - Your `nonzero()`-approach is even much faster than mine :) +1

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use a lookup logic where I have a second array storing the correct indices.

Lets assume we have a random-value-array we boolean masked and want to apply `argmin`/`argmax` on, this would look like:

```py
random_array = np.random.randint(10, size=100)
random_mask  = np.random.randint(2, size=100, dtype=np.bool)

# Returns index of fist occurrence of minimum value within the masked array
random_array[random_mask].argmin()
```

Now we have to create a lookup-table containing the indeces of the unmasked `random_array`:

```py
lookup = np.arange(len(random_array), dtype=np.int))
```

If we now mask the `lookup` in the same way we mask the `random_array`, we retrieve the original index:

```py
# Returns the index within the unmasked array
result = lookup[random_mask][random_array[random_mask].argmin()]
```